# app-indexeddb-mirror with Polymerfire

Tags: polymer, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

I built a simple page that has multiple tabs. Each tab loads a feed (collection/list) of articles from Firebase and renders cards on the page. Everything works as I wanted until I tried to persist the visited feeds into `indexeddb` with `app-indexeddb-mirror`.

Here's what I did:

```
<dom-module id="my-view1">
<template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
    </style>

    <paper-tabs id="tabs"
                attr-for-selected="value"
                selected="{{selectedFeed}}"
                scrollable>
        <template is="dom-repeat"
                  items="[[feeds]]"
                  as="feed">
            <paper-tab value="[[feed.key]]">[[feed.name]]</paper-tab>
        </template>
    </paper-tabs>

    <firebase-query id="[[selectedFeed]]_feed"
                    app-name="myfirebaseapp"
                    path="/myfirebaseappdb/feed/[[selectedFeed]]"
                    data="{{articles}}">
    </firebase-query>

    <app-indexeddb-mirror
            key="[[selectedFeed]]"
            data="[[articles]]"
            persisted-data="{{persistedArticles}}">
    </app-indexeddb-mirror>

    <template is="dom-repeat"
              items="[[persistedArticles]]"
              as="article">
            <paper-card image="[[article.image]]" alt="image">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h1 class="card-text">[[article.title]]</h1>
                    <h4 class="card-text">[[article.abstract]]</h4>
                </div>
            </paper-card>
    </template>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-view1',
        ready: function () {
            this.feeds = [
                {name: "Feed1", key: "feed1"},
                {name: "Feed2", key: "feed2"},
                {name: "Feed3", key: "feed3"},
                {name: "Feed4", key: "feed4"}
            ];
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I want to do is cache each feed into `indexeddb` as an entry (feed name as key and the data as value), so they can be loaded when the app is offline. That's basically what `app-indexeddb-mirror` is for, right?

However I cannot get my head around the data flow between `firebase-query` and `app-indexeddb-mirror`, and I keep getting `indexeddb` entry overwritten/emptied when switching tabs.

Is there something I am not doing right? Thanks.

Comment: When the data from the `firebase-query` changes, the `app-indexeddb-mirror` will cache the data. This means that when you switch tabs, the data will change because the `path` on the `firebase-query` changes which will in turn cause the `app-indexeddb-mirror` element to re-cache the data.

Comment: I hooked a couple observers to print logs and it sure did look like @BenThomas you said. I still cannot figure out how to do this the right way? Can you please shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Once selectedFeed changes, wouldn't it also change the key of app-indexeddb-mirror immediately (data bindings are synchronous)? In that case the cache with previous key should not be cleared/emptied right?

Comment: Yes, I would have expected it to store against the different keys like you said. Maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by swapping firebase-query and app-indexeddb-mirror.
I never knew sequence matters in Polymer, also this order is quite counter-intuitive.

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: What do you mean? Like indexedDB should be above firebase-query?I'm having problem seeing data in chrom dev tools. Do you see your data there? It seems like there's nothing there